# Symfony - PHPUnit list tests

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I am using Symfony 2.5.4 and I am building test using PHPUnit on my Website. I was wondering if there was a way to list all the current implemented tests. I have looked in the `app/console` and there is no command that interact with PHPUnit. My goal is to give this list to the testers so they don't have to test was is already tested by PHPUnit. I would be ok with a way to get all the headers of the test functions or simply the name of the functions.

Comment: All my tests of a bundle are in the bundle in directory `Tests` and the structure within is identical. Every component has a corresponding test with suffix `*Test.php`. There are some test setups which are very different, so I use an underscore in the class and filename. For example a class is called `Complicated.php` than there might be a test for `Complicated_DatabaseCorruptedTest.php` and `Complicated_ThirdPartyServiceUnavailableTest.php`. You can see, if there is no implementation (test fails) or there is no test (no file).

Answer (score 0):

Symfony does not have a command that integrates with PHPUnit. To achive your goal, you can generate a code coverage report as HTML document (e.g. `phpunit -c app --coverage-html=web/coverage src/`) and you can show this report to your testers. You can explain there that they don't have to test functionality covered by tests.
But, in my opinion, your testers should test also the parts of application, that are covered by tests.